# Tag for closed questions?

Tags: discussion, tags, closed-questions

Does it make sense to create a tag for closed questions? I'm not sure it does, but it occurred to me because I thought it might be nice to put that tag on my ignore list.

Answer (score 6):

No, absolutely not. This would be a meta tag and we'd remove it instantly.

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/

If the site has a problem with too many [closed] questions, that's symptomatic of other issues (scope mainly). I don't think that's the case here.

Comment: No it's not the case here. Just a thought. Understood.